# How to count different value occurrences in each hour?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe called `df`, which looks like this: with one column of `timestamp` and a column of `s` with only three possible values `1, 0, -1`. Now I want to count how many `1, 0 ,-1` are in each hour. Could someone help? Thanks.

```
timestamp       s
1/6/2018 23:10  0
1/6/2018 23:15  0
1/6/2018 23:23  0
1/6/2018 23:34  0
1/7/2018 0:05   0
1/7/2018 0:09   0
1/7/2018 0:46   0
1/7/2018 0:49   0
1/7/2018 0:49  -1
1/7/2018 0:52  -1
1/7/2018 1:17   1
1/7/2018 1:26   0
1/7/2018 2:16   0
1/7/2018 2:23   1
1/7/2018 2:27   1
1/7/2018 2:34   0
1/7/2018 2:41   1
1/7/2018 2:43   1
1/7/2018 2:49   1
```

**My desired dataframe looks something like:**

```
timestamp      s_-1 s_0 s_1
1/6/2018 23:00  0   4   0
1/7/2018 0:00   2   4   0
1/7/2018 1:00   0   2   3
1/7/2018 2:00   0   2   5
```

Comment: What specifically have you tried? This isn't a code writing service and the expectation is that you have actually tried something out first. Please edit your question with all relevant details, code, and error messages.

Comment: If you don't know how to start then figure out what you would have to do using paper and pencil and break the problem up into parts. For example, first you would create a place to store tally's for each hour, then you would look at each row determine the hour from the timestamp, then look at the value, and finally add a tally.

Comment: @scrappedcola: Sorry if I appear to be expecting code writing service, I did my research but did not find the clue. Anyway Pax Vobiscum's answer helps me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A *Coarse Grained* Approach Solution *Sketch*:

1. find the smallest timestamp in df and convert i to a datetime object dt with strptime
2. define hours start as `hour_start = dt - timedelta(minutes=dt.minute,seconds=dt.second,microseconds=dt.microsecond)`
3. predefine a list/structure of your choosing with the start of all hours by iterating with a while loop and incrementing hour_start with timedelta as `+= timedelta(hours=1)` and stop when you exceed the last timestamp.
4. loop over dataframe again and decide in which bucket to place each entry

This is a *very blunt strategy*, but you'll have to finish the thought process and then put it into code yourself. Let me know if there is anything you need explaining in more detail.

Comment: Thanks Pax for your sketch, It is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it by creating a dictionary of timestamps up to the date and hour as keys. so your keys would look like `[1/6/2018 23], [1/7/2018 0], ...` and then your values could be a list of the s values and then you can iterate through your dictionary and count!